# Take elements until a certain character and group them with RxJava

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I have a simple setup to a problem but the solution seems to be more complicated.

Setup: I have a hot observable which originates from a scanner that will emit every number as a different element and an `R` when a code is complete.

Problem: From this I want a hot observable that emits every full code as 1 element.

[image: RxMarbles example]

I tried playing around with different `flatMap`, `takeUntil` and `groupBy`operators but haven't been able to come to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *buffer* operator.

```
PublishSubject<Token<Integer>> s = PublishSubject.create();

Observable<Token<Integer>> markers = s.filter(x->x.isMarker());

s.buffer(markers).subscribe(
    v->{
        Optional<Integer> reduce = v.stream()
            .filter(t->!t.isMarker())
            .map(t->(ValueToken<Integer>)t)
            .map(ValueToken::get)
            .reduce((a,b)->a+b);
        reduce.ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }
);

s.onNext(value(12));
s.onNext(value(13));
s.onNext(marker()); // will emit 25

s.onNext(value(10));
s.onNext(value(7));
s.onNext(marker()); // will emit 17

s.onNext(value(10));
s.onNext(value(7)); // Not emitting yet
```

I made a class to wrap both values and markers in the flow.

```
public abstract class Token<T> {
    private static final MarkerToken MARKER = new MarkerToken<>();

    public boolean isMarker() {
        return false;
    }

    public static <T> MarkerToken<T> marker() {
        return MARKER;
    }

    public static <T> ValueToken<T> value(T o) {
        return new ValueToken<>(o);
    }

    public static class ValueToken<T> extends Token<T> {
        T value;

        public ValueToken(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public T get() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static class MarkerToken<T> extends Token<T> {
        public boolean isMarker() {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

### update (using scan)

The previous method would emit also on the closing of the stream, with this solution you can emit **only** complete buffers.

The message class function as an accumulator, it will accumulate tokens until closing marker is accumulated.

When this happens the *next* message will start from scratch.

The presence of the closing mark as last element *marks* the message as complete.

```
public static class Message<T> {
    List<Token<T>> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

    public Message<T> append(Token<T> t) {

        Message<T> mx = new Message<T>();
        if(!isComplete()) {
            mx.tokens.addAll(tokens);
        }
        mx.tokens.add(t);
        return mx;
    }

    public boolean isComplete() {
        int n = tokens.size();
        return n>0 && tokens.get(n-1).isMarker();
    }

    public Optional<List<Token<T>>> fullMessage(){
        return isComplete() ? Optional.of(tokens):Optional.empty(); 
    }
}
```

Scanning the source you emit a message for each token emitted, then you filter out incomplete message and emit just the one marked as complete.

```
    s.scan(new Message<Integer>(), (a, b) -> a.append(b))
        .filter(Message::isComplete)
        .map(Message::fullMessage)
        .map(Optional::get).subscribe(v -> {
            System.out.println(v);
        });

    s.onNext(value(12));
    s.onNext(value(13));
    s.onNext(marker());// [V(12), V(13), MARKER]

    s.onNext(value(10));
    s.onNext(value(7));
    s.onNext(marker()); // [V(10), V(7), MARKER]



    s.onNext(value(10));
    s.onNext(value(127));

    s.onComplete(); // Not emitting incomplete messages on the closing of the subject.
```